# Is it necessary to migrate from ember-data/active-model-adapter to DS.JSONAPISerializer for ember 3?

Tags: serialization, ember.js, backend

Documentation for DS.ActiveModelAdapter is exists only for 1.13 (for 2 - 404:
https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/1.13/classes/DS.ActiveModelAdapter
So, it looks like it's moved out from DS:
https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter

We have ember-data 2.13.2 and it's working fine with `active-model-adapter`
But we got some issues with the bump to ember-data 2.14.11 with nested behavior

The big issue here is to rewrite the backend part.
We also may use RESTAdapter:
https://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/113-restadapter-vs-jsonapiadapter-vs-activemodeladapter
but it looks like ember way is JSONAPIAdapter way:
https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/JSONAPIAdapter

So, generally, the question is: what way is better for ember-upgrade?

- keep backend API and maintain active-model-adapter
- rewrite backend API and migrate to `JSONAPIAdapter` (with data/relationships approach)
- rewrite backend API and migrate to RESTAdapter
- keep backend API and implement custom serializer to change on the fly input/output to use JSONAPIAdapter or RESTAdapter (pick best) logic on FE (maybe it's some crazy way, but it's just to ask)

Note: backend API on RubyOnRails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rewrite of your backend is not needed. Ember Data is flexible enough to handle all REST APIs that follow some convention among their endpoints.

Let's have a look on your specific use case.

`ActiveModelAdapter` and `ActiveModelSerializer` were [deprecated in Ember Data 1.13](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-113-june-16-2015) and [removed in Ember Data 2.0](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3457). But the logic itself is still available through [active-model-adapter](https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter) package.

All that package does is providing a customization of Ember Data's build-in `RestAdapter` and `RestSerializer` packages. If you ignore the in-source documentation it's actually not much code. You can find it in the [`addon/` folder of active-model-adapter package](https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter/tree/master/addon).

So even if this package would not be available you could still customize `RestAdapter` and `RestSerializer` in the same way to support your backend as is.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So, just to clarify: we can keep using active-model-adapter even with Ember 3, but it's nice to migrate into JSONAPIAdapter or RestAdapter with custom support implementation?

Comment: Haven't tested myself how well that addon is working with latest Ember Data. But if you don't face any issues there isn't a reason to change from Ember integration perspective. JSON API specification has some benefits. But you can decide if you want to migrate independently.